# How to move an object to specific coordinates python pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, drawing, shapes

I have a bunch of separate lines, which make up one 'shape', of a 'dog'.

I want to be able to put this shape anywhere on the screen.

For example, my game will generate dogs. If the player has only one dog, I want the first generated dog to be at the top. If they have two, I want the new one to be underneath the first. And so on.

I'm using Python, with PyGame, but I could import a different module.

This is my game code so far:

```
#initialise 
import pygame
pygame.init()

#colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
gameDisplay.fill(white)

#lines (dog)
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (195, 250), (500, 250), 5) #back
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (500, 250), (580, 450), 5) #tail
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (580, 450), (480, 330), 5) #tail
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (480, 330), (480, 500), 5) #back leg
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (480, 500), (450, 500), 5) #back paw
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (450, 500), (450, 350), 5) #back leg
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (450, 350), (200, 350), 5) #belly
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (200, 350), (200, 500), 5) #front leg
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (200, 500), (170, 500), 5) #front paw
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (170, 500), (170, 300), 5) #front leg
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, (150, 260), 50, 5) #head

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: have you tried OOP?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.draw.lines`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines) instead of [`pygame.draw.lines`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line). `pygame.draw.lines` draws multiple contiguous straight line segments.

e.g.:

```py
points = [(195, 250), (500, 250), (580, 450), (480, 330)]
pygame.draw.lines(gameDisplay, black, False, points, 5)
```

Use [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a new list with translated coordinates:

```py
def draw_lines(surf, color, trans_x, trans_y, points, width=0):
    trans_points = [(trans_x + p[0], trans_y + p[1]) for p in points]
    pygame.draw.lines(surf, color, False, trans_points, width)
```

```py
draw_lines(gameDisplay, black, False, 100, 100, points, 5)
```